# Consequences of including an external script file in a GTM tag

Tags: google-tag-manager

In GTM, lets say that I have a "custom HTML" tag, and in it include an external script file like

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://externalsite.com/file.js"></script>`

How is this file loaded? Does it affect the loading time of the page?

I know that the GTM script is loaded asynchronously along with the tags, but I can't really imagine what happens in this case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In you GTM custom HTML tag, you can even use the async or defer attributes:

```
<script async type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/file.js"></script>
```

Further reading: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-async

And if you are using HTML5, type defaults to `text/javascript`, so you can leave it off.

Alternatively you could load asynchronously using an anonymous self invoking function:

```
<script>
(function(d,s){
var e = d.createElement(s),
m = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
e.async = 1;
e.src = '//externalsite.com/file.js';
m.parentNode.insertBefore(e,m);
})(document,'script');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. But what I want to know is: is there a difference between having the script in the tag with and without the async attribute, since the whole GTM script is async?

Comment: Since the GTM tag is async, it is not "blocking" the page from rendering. Any html scripts executed by GTM would be blocking relative to GTM, and not the page. So, is there any difference? Yes. One is blocking, one is not. Real world? You probably wouldn't even notice it. Async is preferable as it keeps the event loop free. Which means better concurrency.

Comment: Adding `async` would not make any difference. GTM doesn't use that HTML directly, instead it looks for `src` and injects a DOM script element directly. That is always async.

Answer (score 1):

> How is this file loaded?

Asyncronously, keeping script order.
Despite you writing it as an html `<script>` tag, GTM loads it creating a DOM script element instead.
This is roughly the code used (not taken from GTM directly as minified):

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = '/path/to/file.js';
script.async = false;
```

> Does it affect the loading time of the page?

Yes. While the way GTM loads scripts [impacts page loading speed as little as possible](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/#toc-dom-rescue), scripts still have a [significant impact](https://web.dev/bootup-time/#how-javascript-execution-slows-down-performance).
There are ways to [mitigate the impact](https://web.dev/fast#optimize-your-third-party-resources), although third parties are generally  harder to optimise.

Comment: About loading time, [this blog post](http://blog.catchpoint.com/2015/04/14/holes-google-tag-managers-async-loading/) suggests loading time can actually suffer severely in some scenarios.

Comment: From experience, GTM can severely impact the page load. I don't control what Marketing puts inside Tag Manager but I can remove it to perform tests, and the page load is affected by a whooping 3 seconds (until usable, not full page load). It all depends on what is put inside, they added IBM Tealeaf at the beforeunload event, a websocket chat app, dom changing JS, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Any external script placed in the GTM custom HTML tag will be loaded in the similar manner as other tags load. As GTM tags are loaded asynchronously, it wont affect the loading time of the page.